# Is yarn global add broken on Windows?

Tags: windows, npm, yarnpkg

When I install react-native-cli with `yarn add global react-native-cli` on Windows 7 or 10, it won't run. The PATH is set properly, and `npm install -g react-native-cli` works fine. I tested with other packages, they act the same. I tested on MacOS and Ubuntu Bash inside Windows 10, and those both work fine.

I'm using yarn 0.27.5, and have tried both node 6.10 and 7.8.

My current workaround is to use npm for global installs, but I'd prefer to use yarn for consistency (and npm 5 has its own Windows-specific issues).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the same issue by ensuring the result of `yarn global bin` is added to both the user environment variables' `%PATH%` and to the system environment variables' `%PATH%`. I only had it in the user ones and that didn't work.